# How to handle huge (~3 gb) xml, parse it into json in python. Using xml.etree to iterate over it but memory error

Tags: python, json, xml, memory-management, nlp

I need to convert terminological resource IATE to json in a specific format for further processing. I am using xml.etree to iterate through the xml, conditionally check the tags and add relevant texts into a dictionary. I need a list of these dictionaries as an output.

As the size of this final list of dictionaries can be huge depending on the data hence I plan to take note of the length of this list and after a certain value, write it as json and carry on.

Although code does what it is supposed to but it gives memory errors although I tried >> del  to practically no use. I understand python doesn't actually return the memory back to the os and having a new reference in the loop should automatically handle it (eventually).

Please let me know what is causing memory troubles and how to do it in an efficient manner.

```
parser = ET.iterparse(file_name, events = ["start","end"])

l= []
len_list = 0
file_num = 1

for event, element in parser:
    if element.tag == "tag1" and event == "start":
        dic = {}
        dic["@id"] = element.attrib["id"]
        dic["label"] = {}
        dic["description"] = {}
        dic["relations"] = {}

    if element.tag == "tag2" and event == "start":
        lang = element.attrib.values()[0]
        dic["label"][lang] = []

    if element.tag == "tag3" and event == "start":
        dic["label"][lang].append(element.text)

    if element.tag == "tag1" and event == "end":
        l.append(dic)
        del dic
        del lang
        len_list += 1

    if len_list == 5000:
        print "writing file: " + str(file_num)
        iate_json = {"entities": l}
        with open(path_to_output_dir + str(file_num) + ".json",'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(iate_json, outfile, indent = 4)

        del l
        l = []
        len_list = 0
        file_num += 1

iate_json = {"entities": l}
with open(path_to_output_dir + str(file_num) + ".json",'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(iate_json, outfile, indent = 4)
```

Let me know both mistakes in the code and also any other optimum way to achieve the same task. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone still struggling on this problem, I added 
`element.clear()`
after every instance i capture the element.

Although it is mentioned at many places but I am still to find some resource where it explains how xml.etree handle memory internally. Any leads will be appreciated.

Thank you